# how to set the value to primary key identity column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table containing 2000 records in it in Sql server 2008 R2. It does not have Primary Key column. I have to add one primary key identity column.

How can I assign values to Primary key column in one go?

Comment: You're probably talking about adding an `identity` column, but you should be aware that `identity` and `primary key` are *not* synonyms. You can have one without the other.

Comment: I want that column should be Primary key first. Once i got unique values in it, I can make it as identity. I can't make it as Primary key as table contains 2000 records. I don't want to remove the records. How can I achieve it?

Comment: If you just add an `identity` column to an existing table, each row will be assigned a unique value as it is added.

Comment: OH... Yes problem solved. I tried it earlier, it did not happen. Ok. No issues. Thank you very much. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a column that's an `IDENTITY` column, use this command:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD YourNewColumn INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

This will add a new column that's an `IDENTITY` column to your table, and it will assign values to that column for all existing rows.

And to make it the primary key, use this command

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(YourNewColumn)
```

Or if you want to, you can add it in a single command:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD YourNewColumn INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
   CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio then
Right Click on the column and select Primary Key from the drop down.